# Angular HTML Markup - Table causing error

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a value foo, and this code displays its properties correctly with the following code:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <p> {{ foo.name }} </p>
    <p visible = "foo.description"> {{ foo.description }}</p>
    <p> {{foo.tags }} </p>
    <p visible = "foo.instructions"> {{ foo.instructions }} </p>
</div>
```

It displays four paragraphs, each with the value of foo.*property*

However, when I add a table underneath:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <p> {{ foo.name }} </p>
    <p visible = "foo.description"> {{ foo.description }}</p>
    <p> {{ foo.tags }} </p>
    <p visible = "foo.instructions"> {{ foo.instructions }} </p>
    <table class="table table-hover">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>File Name</th>
          <th>File Type</th>
          <th>File Size</th>
          <th> 3D View </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat-start="file in foo.fileId">
          <td> filler </td>
          <td> filler </td>
          <td> filler</td>
          <td> filler </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

The values now show literally as {{ foo.description }} rather than showing the value. Why would adding a simple table mess that up?

Comment: Is 'foo' supposed to change to 'model'?

Comment: I just generalize my variable names when posting and wasn't cautious - in the original code they are all consistent.

Comment: The only error that is possible is that 'foo.fileId' isn't an array.

Comment: In the version without the table I added a <p> for {{ foo.fileId }} and it's definitely an array: ["56463150b479ab282ac6a036"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, I figured it out. You have an 'ng-repeat-start' but you never end it. You need to include an 'ng-repeat-end'. Or, just use the normal 'ng-repeat' and then you don't have to specify a start and an end. This works:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
 <p> {{ foo.name }} </p>
 <p visible = "foo.description"> {{ foo.description }}</p>
 <p> {{ foo.tags }} </p>
 <p visible = "foo.instructions"> {{ foo.instructions }} </p>
 <table class="table table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>File Name</th>
      <th>File Type</th>
      <th>File Size</th>
      <th> 3D View </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="file in foo.fileId">
      <td> filler </td>
      <td> filler </td>
      <td> filler</td>
      <td> filler </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you! I copied it from another file I had where I did have an ng-repeat-end, and forgot to take that out! Hope you didn't spend too long on it.

Comment: No, not at all. I don't know why I didn't see that at first.

Comment: Also, I don't know how familiar you are with dev tools but if you open up the browser's console whenever there's an angular error, it usually tells you exactly what the error is.

Comment: Don't forget to accept my answer if it solved your problem.